# tag com display: none - asp net

Tags: css, asp.net

Tenho algumas tags `<h3>`, `<p>` com `display: none` ou então vazias (geralmente as uso para exibir mensagens ou algumas div), ao clicar em algum evento do sistema, estas tags aparecem: `display: block` ou então são preenchidas pelo `innerHTML`. Quando clico em um outro evento, estas tags voltam ao que eram no início: `display: none` ou vazias.

Tem como fazer com que elas não voltem ao estado inicial? Ou seja, quando clicar no evento em que as fizerem aparecer, elas ficarem assim até que eu queira desativá-las novamente. Porque no segundo evento que clicar, pode ser o caso de que essas tags devam ficar ativadas, entendeu? Logo eu não precisaria chamar um método que as ative novamente. Quando eu precisar desativá-las, basta passar o `display: none` (como era no início). Deu pra entender?

Então, o que acontece é que toda vez que aciono um evento ocorre um postBack, correto? E essas tags (div, h3) voltam aos seus valores iniciais. Não é algo que eu mandei fazer, eu não queria que voltassem a seus valores iniciais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem duas regras de ouro no mundo da programação:

1. Computador não pensa: ele não analisa e toma nenhuma decisão diferente do que ele foi instruído a fazer;
2. Computador não erra: ele fazer exatamente o que foi instruído a fazer, exatamente;

Isso se aplica no seu cenário, se um objeto está tendo seu estado alterado, é pq existe algo que o está alterando. Fato.

Deve-se então descobrir qual ação está fazendo isso, e condicionar a não fazer mais.

Tentar impedir que o estado seja alterado, sem identificar quem está fazendo isso e o motivo, é como um carro com tanque de combustível furado, mas ao invés de consertar o furo, simplismente está anexando um outro tanque sobre ele para que o combustível não acabe tão depressa.

Descubra o motivo que seu objecto está tendo seu estado restaurado, assim irá resolver o problema definitivamente, e com menor custo de processamento possível.

Comment: Eu simplesmente crio uma <div>, esta possui alguns dados a serem apresentados, eu a deixo como display: none. Quando preciso mostrá-la, eu altero para display: block. Só que ao clicar em um outro evento (de um botão ou um selectedIndexChanged) elas voltam ao valor inicial de "none", acredito que seja porque os eventos fazem um postBack. Então será isso mesmo: toda vez que acontece um postBack as tags voltam ao estado inicial?

Comment: Sim, cada postbabk o HTML é recriado. Não é nem a mesma tag, é uma completamente nova.

Comment: Eu achei isso bem chato, cara. Então não há o que fazer? Eu tenho que chamar as funções novamente para que passem para o display: block tudo de novo?

Comment: Na vdd há várias coisas que pode-se fazer. Por estar usando MVC com Razor, recomendo [criar um Html Helper](http://www.devmedia.com.br/html-helpers-criando-componentes-web-customizados-em-asp-net-mvc/27703) que irá retornar esse `<div>` sendo exibido ou não. Outra forma é setar `display:none/block;` usando `ViewBag` orientado pelo postback anterior. Por ultimo, e que eu recomendo não fazer, é colocar um `@if` na View e ali setar o `display` do `<div>`.

Comment: Não estou usando MVC, se este resolve esse tipo de problema, então vou estudá-lo.

Comment: Esta fazendo com WebForms estão? Tipo, com UpdatePanel?

Comment: Com WebForms, chamo as funções JS com um Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock().

Comment: Sim, usando isso vc tem que recuperar todos os estados do HTML. E fuja do WebForms assim que possivel.

Comment: Obrigado, pois é, achei isso de recuperar todos os estados das tags um saco, cara, vou estudar o MVC. Valeu!

Comment: Tem algum livro/ apostila pra me recomendar?

Comment: Canal oficial do ASP.NET - https://www.asp.net/learn